# Given rm why does rmdir exist?

Tags: command-line, rm

Is there any resultant difference on disk between using rm or rmdir to remove a directory?

Or is it only different by usage preference, By example, given

```
$ mkdir a
$ mkdir a/b
$ mkdir a/b/c
```

Would

```
$ rmdir -p a/b/c
```

have the same effect as

```
$ rm -r a
```

just looking at it from a different end?

Comment: `rmdir` is  a little safer, sometimes.  If you issue `mkdir test` and then `touch test\a` and then `rmdir test`, you will get an error that the directory is not empty.  If you issue `rm -r test`.....

Comment: Thanks Charles.  That does appear to be another context usage difference to keep in mind. :) I am still curious to know if **rmdir** does something extra on disk that **rm -r** does not.

Comment: There is a good hystorical essay about this on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/430313/what-is-the-reason-for-rmdir1-and-rm1-to-co-exist)

Comment: `rmdir` removes only empty directories , while `rm -r` will remove even non-empty directories

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rmdir` will only remove empty directories while `rm -r` will remove directories and files within them recursively. Thus, it is safer to use rmdir.

It can save one when hidden files get involved since a `cp *` or `mv *` won't copy or move the hidden files along with the rest. `rmdir` will refuse to delete the folder if there is anything in, even hidden files so it serves as a additional protection in cases like these. Of course, you could just do `rm -ri` if you wanted to be really careful, but personally, I find `rmdir` much faster.